# Optimizing NHibernate generated SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have an NHibernate LINQ query like this:

```
var maxNumber = session
    .Linq<Child>()
    .Where(c => c.Parent == parent)
    .Max(c => c.Number);
```

NHibernate generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT max(this_.Number) 
FROM [Child] as this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Parent] parent1_
ON this_.Parent_id = parent1_.Id
WHERE parent1_.Id = @p0
```

I would like it to simply generate something like:

```
SELECT max(this_.Number) 
FROM [Child] as this_
WHERE this_.Parent_id = @p0
```

I would have expected that execution plans would be exactly the same for both queries, but this isn't the case.

My entities are defined like this:

```
class Parent
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    int Number { get; set; }
    Parent Parent { get; set; } // mapped as FK
}
```

With mapping like this:

```
class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
        Map(x => x.Number);
        References(x => x.Parent);
    }
}
```

How could I rewrite it to get the latter output using NHibernate? This is done inside a repository method, so I can easily switch to HQL or something else if needed (or of course a plain `DbCommand` if everything else fails).

I am using NHibernate 2.0 with LINQ-to-NHibernate and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Using NH 3.2 I got the optimized query.  I'm guessing 2.0 just isn't as intelligent in the query building.  And because of that, I'm not sure HQL will solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I create the query and explicitly specify the Id is the property I want to query on, rather than the entity I get the "optimized" query. i.e.:

```
session
    .Query<Child>()
    .Where(c => c.Parent.Id = parent.Id)
    .Max(c = c.Number);
```

Comment: Hm, I tried that and I'm pretty sure that gave me the same result, but I might have done something wrong, I'll check it now. (edit:) No, it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps it's NH version as @JayOtterbein mentioned?

Comment: I finally decided to switch to NH 3.2. LINQ provider in NH2 was buggy all the time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Query<>` you can't be using NHibernate 2.0.

Assuming that's a typo and you meant 3.0, try updating to 3.2. I've just verified your query works exactly as expected.

Now, there **is** a bug in 3.2 that causes an extra join if you write your query like this:

```
var maxNumber = session
    .Query<Child>()
    .Where(c => c.Parent.Id == parent.Id)
    .Max(c => c.Number);
```

...And this is fixed in 3.3 (a pre-release version is out since yesterday)

Comment: It's NH2, but I forgot to mention I am using LINQ2NHibernate, which was merged with NH in v3 IIRC.

Comment: The old LINQ provider is accessed using `session.Linq<>`, not `session.Query<>`. The provider in NH 3 was written from scratch, is totally unrelated to the old one, and works for most reasonable cases. I suggest that you upgrade.

Comment: Ok, **that** was the typo. :) Nevermind, I hacked the `DBCommand` manually inside my repository method since it's a short one, and it's a relatively old project so I wanted to avoid upgrading at this time.